# How to real-time character recognition with python and camera?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, kivy

I'm making kivy app to recognize character with camera on real-time.
However, there is no document except recognizing face.
I think there is a way because picamera is almost doing similar thing (creating opencv file from camera).

Would someone tell me to achieve this?

*** PS ***
I'm on the way to capture image when camera sees the number, but I don't know how to make that trigger.
Now this is the code, and I want to know when to break true sentence.

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        ret, image = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('image', image)
        results = tes.image_to_string(image, boxes=True)
        if results:
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print(results)
```

but this one is too slow

Answer (score 0):

How about using [pytesseract 0.2.4](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) for that purpose? It looks like best solution, according to dr. Google

Comment: Thank you Fillip, I tried but it only detects image file, not directly live-camara.

Comment: How about if you capture the image every let's say 300ms, and work on it as normal image?
[Simillar topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574637/auto-capture-an-image-from-a-video-in-opencv-using-python)
[Simillar topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943227/python-opencv-capture-images-from-webcam)

Comment: that may work...but may be slow. thanks anyway, until the idea comes up, I will do that way

Comment: I don't think you even have to save it. You can just take frame and work on it, as described in [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that only capturing is not requiring saving! It might be help, I'm going to work in that way!